# MongoDB cursor not found. Can't set noTimeout

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use a Mongoose cursor iterate through a Mongo database hosted in Atlas. This works perfectly find for an undetermined amount of time and then all of the sudden throws a MongoError: cursor id  not found and will not recover (just keeps throwing same error over and over). It appears to get hung up on the same ID more often than not.

There are only around 2000 entries in my DB and I don't think I am doing anything too crazy here. Ideally this would start over when it reaches the end and run infinitely.

My research has shown that the cursor may be timing out and to try setting the timeout to false. Since this is hosted in Atlas that immediately throws an error saying that timeouts aren't allowed on the free tier of Atlas. Not really sure where to go from here.

I appreciate the help in advance. This is driving me crazy!!!

```
let person = '';
let cursor;
const timer = setInterval(async () => {
    try {
        
        person = cursor && (await cursor.next());

        /* If the cursor exists get the next person, else get a new cursor */
        if (person) {
            console.log(person.get('name'));
            //Do stuff
        } else {
            console.log('Acquiring cursor...');
            cursor = await TableName.find({}, '_id id_str name screen_name').cursor();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Cursor error... ${e.stack}`);
    }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: See 'cursors' under https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/#operational-limitations.  I ran into this the other day and unfortunately had to upgrade to a dedicated cluster to meet my use case, which seemed to fix it.  You might be able to get away with just recreating the cursor, depending on your needs.  I wish this aspect were a little better documented.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up having to settle with gracefully failing when the error was thrown.